# Including JS files in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am wondering what's the best way to include .JS files.. let's say Jquery or any custom JS file that you might have developed as part of your custom solutions? I know there are several options like referring from Master pages, delegate control etc. Does sharepoint 2010 has better ways to do it? Will that technique work with Sandboxed solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the blog below has several options if that fits your need:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx